# Rails 6 How to properly test for Enums _scopes: false

Tags: rspec, scope, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rails 6 application.
I am using `rspec` to test
my model looks like this

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ... 
  enum status: [:sold_out, :active, :archived], _scopes: false
  ...
end
```

now my test loos like this

```
it { is_expected.to define_enum_for(:status).with_values([:sold_out, :active, :archived]) }
 # this returns an error
```

Expected Task to define :status as an enum backed by an integer, mapping
‹"sold_out"› to ‹0›, ‹"active"› to ‹1›, ‹"archived"› to
‹2›. :status does map to
these values, but the enum is (we can't tell which).

Now if I remove `_scopes: false` the test passed. but how can I make my test pass keeping the `_scopes: false`

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar issue today. Solution was to add `.with_prefix(:foo)` to the spec, where `foo` is the name of the enum column. For example:

```rb
is_expected.to define_enum_for(:status)
  .with_values(:sold_out, :active :archived)
  .with_prefix(:status)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [Shoulda Matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)?

Assuming you are, [define_enum_for](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/c47e6db7391963d27cb9b45c37d9aa94e53f0590/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/define_enum_for_matcher.rb#L229) looks like it checks for existence of [value methods](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/c47e6db7391963d27cb9b45c37d9aa94e53f0590/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/define_enum_for_matcher.rb#L380), which are created automatically but [won't be available when you disable scopes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

If you need to disable scopes, I would consider writing a custom matcher without the value methods test.